# How to add one row to a dataframe

Tags: r

Im not sure why a) I cant do this and b) I cant find the answer to this. All I want to do is add one row to a dataframe as follows
     `rbind(data.frame(Names = "FS", Values = 2377), result)`

The dataframe is called result. The two columns in it are called Names and Values.
When I run the above there is no error but also nothing gets added. Am I doing this correctly?
The dataframe is as follows

```
   Names    Values
    (A)n    96
(AAATG)n    106
(AAGTG)n    19
(AATAG)n    2
(ACATG)n    28
```

The results I get are that the dataframe doesnt change at all

Comment: Can you describe your dataFrame & results.

Comment: @user3632206 I couldn't reproduce your situation. `result <- data.frame(Names=LETTERS[1:3], Values=1:3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE); rbind(data.frame(Names = "FS", Values = 2377), result)`

Comment: here is the dataframe

Comment: @user3632206  Based on the updated dataset, I don't find any problems in rbind

Comment: It got added at the top.  `rbind` binds in the order of the given arguments in `...`

Comment: So how the provided answer was different from what you tried? Did you just forgot to assign the result into new variable?

Comment: Yes. I guess I thought I could add it straight into rbind as a declared dataframe but it looks like I had to create a dataframe first and then add it.

Comment: No you don't, you can just do `Res <- rbind(data.frame(Names = "FS", Values = 2377), result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this type of approach:-

```
x <- data.frame(Names="FS",Values=2377)
results <- data.frame(Names="SF",Values=10)
temp <- rbind(x,results)
print(temp)
```

It is working, first data frame has 1 row then after rbind row get addes to data frame. Results should be of same format.

```
>print(x)
  Names Values
1    SF     10
>print(temp)
  Names Values
1    FS   2377
2    SF     10
```

Comment: Actually you just copy/pasted the code given by the OP. There is no difference between `rbind(data.frame(Names = "FS", Values = 2377), result)` and `x <- data.frame(Names="FS",Values=2377); rbind(x,results)`. The only thing that matters here is that you saved it into `temp` - which is the answer to the question.